# How to use multiple strategies in passportjs

Tags: node.js, express, google-oauth, passport.js

I have 2 social authentication strategies in my node js app. one is google-OAuth and another one is github. There will be more strategies as well (azure-ad and email-password).

How can I combine multiple strategies in one `passport.authenticate` function?

Currently, I am using it like following:

```
router
    .route('/hello')
    .get(
        passport.authenticate('google', { successRedirect: '/v1/any', failureRedirect: '/login', scope: ['email', 'profile'] }),
        (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
            try {
                return res.locals.success('Hello World');
            } catch (error) {
                next(error);
            }
        }
    );
```

below is the github strategy:

```
router
    .route('/hello1')
    .get(
        passport.authenticate('github', { successRedirect: '/v1/any', failureRedirect: '/login', scope: ['user:email'] }),
        (req, res, next) => {
            try {
                return res.locals.success('Hello World');
            } catch (error) {
                next(error);
            }
        }
    );
```

(ofcourse, this is not in production)

I have read a solution where I can pass the array of strategies in the passport.authenticate method's first argument, But that will not work as scopes are different for google and github

Or I can use it only like this?

```
router.route('/hello').get(
  (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const strategies = [
      { name: 'google', scope: ['email', 'profile'] },
      { name: 'github', scope: ['user:email'] },
    ];

    const { strategy } = req.query;
    const strategyConfig = strategies.find((s) => s.name === strategy);

    if (strategyConfig) {
      passport.authenticate(strategyConfig.name, {
        scope: strategyConfig.scope,
      })(req, res, next);
    } else {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid authentication strategy' });
    }
  },
  (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
      return res.locals.success('Hello World');
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  }
);
```